# Xamarin letter spacing in password entry

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have written custom renderer in ios for entry type to add letter space. It works when entry is not set for password type. How can I achieve this behavior for password entry?

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        var element = Element as PassowrdEntry;
        if (element == null)
            return;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Element.Text))
        {
            Control.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(Element.Text, new UIStringAttributes
            {
                Font = Control.Font,
                KerningAdjustment = 8
            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: Letter space "Black string" you want at start, mid or end of the string ?

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi want to add space between each and every entered password letters.

Comment: Adding space will be done automatically or you want user should be able to type space while entering password

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi What I want is add letter space between password letters(rounded dots). Not to add empty space

Comment: @IshanthaKamal Hi , you can execute your `AttributedText` code into `Control.TextChanged` method to have a try.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's working I just increased the `KerningAdjustment` value to 10.

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    var element = Element as CustomEntry;
    if (element == null)
        return;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Element.Text))
    {
        Control.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(Element.Text, new UIStringAttributes
        {
            Font = Control.Font,
            KerningAdjustment = 10
        });
    }
}
```

**Xaml:**

```
<ctrl:CustomEntry Placeholder="Enter Pass"
                  IsPassword="True"/>
```

[image]

Comment: What I actually want is to increase the space between letters.Not to add space. I have written a customer renderer for andriod, but as in code sample for ios renderer, it only works when IsPassword mode is not enabled.

Comment: Hi @Himanshu Dwivedi. Can I know the xamarin forms version you used? Because it does not work for after updating the value

Comment: My Xamarin Version 4.0